# What is the reference to an emplaced instance invalidated?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class that stores some data and also a member that needs to modify some of the parent class data. Consider the following simplified example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Modifier {
  std::vector<std::string> &stuff;

  Modifier(std::vector<std::string> &ref) : stuff(ref) {}
  void DoIt() {
      std::cout << "stuff.size = " << stuff.size() << '\n';
  }
};

struct Container {
  std::vector<std::string> stuff;
  Modifier modifier;

  std::vector<std::string> BuildStuff(int n) {
      return std::vector<std::string>{"foo", std::to_string(n)};
  }
  Container(int n) : stuff(BuildStuff(n)), modifier(stuff) {}
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Container> containers;
  containers.emplace_back(5);
  containers.emplace_back(42);
  containers[0].modifier.DoIt();
  containers[1].modifier.DoIt();
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this, one of the emplaced instances correctly reports size `2`, but the other one reports size `0`. I assume there's some undefined behaviour happening due to emplacing, but I cannot pinpoint what is the root cause.

Also, is there a more elegant way to represent this scenario?

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e68ae9bf2b7e6b75

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do the second `emplace_back`, the vector may undergo a reallocation operation: in order to grow, it allocates a new memory block and moves the objects from the old to the new, and frees the old memory block.

Your `Modifier` object generates a dangling reference when moved: the target object's reference refers to the same object that the old reference did.

To fix this you could add a move-constructor to `Container`, and either add or delete the copy-constructor.  The `Modifier` has to be initialized to refer to the `Container` it is a member of;  but the default copy- and move-constructors will initialize the `Modifier` to refer to the source being copy/move'd from.

For example:

```
Container(Container&& o) : stuff(std::move(o.stuff)), modifier(stuff) {}
Container(Container const& o) : stuff(o.stuff), modifier(stuff) {}
```