# When std::vector push_back() the object which has the reference member

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


class myClass {
public:
    double a;
    double& ref;
    myClass() : ref(a)
    {
        a = 1;
    }
    ~myClass() {}
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<myClass> myVector;
    int nIter = 5;
    while (nIter--) {
        myVector.push_back(myClass());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hi.

I have myClass and I would like to push_back the myClasses and bring them together in one vector.
**But unfortunately,** **I have to use a reference in myClass**.
The problem is when the temporary object destructs, the reference becomes invalid and vector contains the object whose reference is invalidated. 
After investigating, I was able to see that those reference variables are pointing at (referencing) the same memory.
I would like to find the way where **each vector's element's reference member variable references each vector's element's a(member variable).**
Is there any way to achieve this..?

[image]

- Addition
  I would like to describe my situation further.
  I have one middle-sized project. In there, the users have the option to choose which variable among member variables will be used in my algorithm. so I made the script in which ref variable is used so that it can change according to the option.
  I hope my explanation was clear.

Comment: If the default copy-constructor doesn't do what you expect, why won't you implement the copy-constructor, that does?

Comment: Whats the point of the reference if it references a variable in the same class?

Comment: @tkausl Can you say in other words..?

Comment: Why do you have to use a self referential reference? High chance of XY problem.

Comment: You should add a copy-constructor and move-constructor that initializes the reference to the right `a`

Comment: @AntonioSEO In other words, remove the reference and try to explain the _real_ problem your trying to solve with the reference.

Comment: @Eljay if you suggest these to a beginner they almost certainly now have two problems. Let's not jump the gun.

Comment: @NirFriedman I do know that It is risky and inefficient. but there is the chance that my users change the reference variable's reference target.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717780/

Comment: @AntonioSEO How would you expect the user to change the reference target?

Comment: I can't say for sure but it is very likely that the correct solution to your problem involves eliminating the reference variable. If I were you I'd create a new question, explaining why you use it, (with self contained example) and asking how to change your code to avoid it.

Comment: You can't change a reference after its initialisation. You can only change the value it refers to, which - again - boils down to _use `a` directly_.

Comment: @ AlgirdasPreidžius Please check, I edited my post

Comment: *"...is referencing each vector's a(member variable)"* - `a` isn't a member of a vector; it's a member of `myClass`. Take a breath, stop thinking about code, and describe the *problem* being solved; *not* the problem with your solution.

Comment: @tkausl But the thing is a is no longer valid here..

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh I changed, each vector's element's member. I will take you advice

Comment: @AntonioSEO 1) The explanation are clearer, when they are done in code, not words. 2) Again, what's wrong with defining your own copy-constructor, if the default one doesn't do what you need?

Comment: It is highly likely the very first comment in this wall of text is applicable to the issue you're having with your code as-is. [See it live](https://ideone.com/aAxupk). Whether any of that is applicable to the choice of solution you're attempting is another issue entirely, but it would none-the-less seem to solve your most-immediate concern.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Well... even if I define copy-constructor, how can I use that? which object should I copy?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Thank you so much, I didn't know copy constructor will be automatically called while push_back ing. Thank you!

Comment: @AntonioSEO "_I didn't know copy constructor will be automatically called while push_back ing._" Did you try reading the documentation of [`std::vector::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)? "_The new element is initialized as a copy of value._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this behavior because you are initializing your 'ref' member to a value that is on the stack, then the default copy constructor is copying that into the vector.

For example, in my debugger the value I have for ref is:

```
+       &myVector[1].ref    0x00eff80c {2.0000000000000000} double *
+       &myVector[1]    0x00126940 {a=2.0000000000000000 ref=2.0000000000000000 }   
+       myVector    { size=0x00000002 } std::vector<myClass,std::allocator<myClass> >
+       &nIter  0x00eff8f0 {0xffffffff} int *
```

You can see that `myVector[1].ref` is not inside `myVector[1]` as you'd expect, and is, in fact, on the stack. You can see that nIter and ref are only 57 bytes apart:

```
&nIter - (int*)&myVector[0].ref 57
```

If you want to see how this is implicitly happening you can delete your copy constructor:

```
myClass(myClass const &rhs) = delete;
```

inside myClass and you'll get an error at push_back.

Another option is to write your own copy constructor:

```
myClass(myClass const &rhs) : ref(a) {
  a = rhs.a;
}
```

If you debug this you'll see that the values are correct, and that the memory locations of each ref are now inside the bounds of the myClass objects.

Finally you might be able to use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`, which will construct `myClass` directly in the vector's memory instead of calling the copy ctor, though I wouldn't recommend this as it leaves this ref copy bug.

also don't forget the assignment operator if you go the copy ctor route: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)

e.g.

```
myClass baz;
baz = myVector[0];
```

this will invoke operator= and not the copy ctor. My compiler (visual studio c++ latest) automatically deletes operator= if you declare a copy ctor, so it would catch this, but your compiler may not.

Comment: Thank you Aaron, I didn't expect that while pushing back, the copy constructor is called.
thank you so much for your help

Comment: myClass(const myClass& rClass) : ref(a)
 {
  a = rClass.a;
 }

I only added this line :) Thank you so much